# Gremlin how do I get the outV of Edge?

Tags: gremlin

Let's say I want to filter my `Edge`s by the `outV`.

Can't seem to figure out what to do after `g.E().hasLabel('HasGeneralPhoneLineType')`

I've tried:

`g.E().hasLabel('HasGeneralPhoneLineType').has('outV','42495ed9-7026-4ba4-9b64-4b05fc860bb0')`

and

`g.E().hasLabel('HasGeneralPhoneLineType').outV()`
gives me back the Vertexes but then how do I filter to get a specific vertex if I know the ID? Something like `g.E().hasLabel('HasGeneralPhoneLineType').outV('abc-123')` or `g.E().hasLabel('HasGeneralPhoneLineType').outV().hasId('abc-123')` or something like that??!?! idk...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it in your other experiments. Try this

```java
g.E().hasLabel('HasGeneralPhoneLineType').
      where(outV().hasId('abc-123'))
```